# How can I make to jQuery Libraries not effect each other?

Tags: jquery, conflict

My to jQuery sources are conflicting with each other. The libraries contain the same letter variables. In other words compressed.js and google.com/jsapi. Use the same variables is there a simple way around this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="compressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('slideshow').style.display='none';
$('wrapper2').style.display='block';
var slideshow=new TINY.slideshow("slideshow");
window.onload=function(){
    slideshow.auto=false;
    slideshow.speed=5;
    slideshow.info="information";
    slideshow.thumbs="slider";
    slideshow.left="slideleft";
    slideshow.right="slideright";
    slideshow.scrollSpeed=4;
    slideshow.spacing=5;
    slideshow.active="#fff";
    slideshow.init("slideshow","image");
}
</script>
```

Second conflicting set:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en', style : google.loader.themes.SHINY});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('012677673255316824096:sean13fvlei');
customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
options.setSearchFormRoot('cse-search-form');
customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
  }, true);
</script>
```

Comment: It does make me wonder why these scripts are using global variables in the first place.

Comment: Which variable names are conflicting?

Comment: I'd imagine it's "options" loads of plugins use that. Some even have it as global.

Comment: @ Matt Ball the variables that are conflicting are in the linked scripts. I was reading something about a NoConflict(); jQuery code will that work to stop the codes from conflicting?

Comment: the conflicting variables are contained in the www.etterengineering.com/compressed.js and http://google.com/jsapi                                                                             @Matt Ball, at least this is what I believe through process of elimination.

Comment: Oh! I see. Without the full URL, there was no way to see the script loaded by this tag: `<script type="text/javascript" src="compressed.js"></script>`.

Comment: Do you see where my dilemma is? I have the compressed.js file on my server so I would prefer to edit that code. do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I do - see my answer. You're basically trying to use Prototype and jQuery in the same page. They are two completely different libraries which both define `$`. If this is the only place you're using Prototype, I'd honestly just get rid of it, since there are plenty of jQuery slideshow plugins you could use instead - and you won't have to worry about this sort of conflict.

Comment: If I could get rid of it I would, that prototype code is across 20 pages all with different content. I would rather attempt to make them work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the JavaScript file in this script tag ([full URL](http://www.etterengineering.com/compressed.js)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="compressed.js"></script>
```

Defines this function:

```
function $(i) {
    return document.getElementById(i)
}
```

But `$` is a variable used by jQuery - so the suggestions to use [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) were accidentally correct. You're trying to use [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and jQuery, both of which try to use `$`. The [Tiny Slideshow](http://slidershowcase.com/jquery-sliders/tiny-slideshow) you're using is for Prototype, not jQuery - just because a library defines `$` doesn't mean it's jQuery!

So, yes, you should read, **understand**, and use the [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) instructions.

Comment: Am I just renaming the var $ or do I have to individually rename every repeat letter var such as m , a , b ,c and so on?

Comment: Since you're going to use Prototype and jQuery side-by-side, you just need to do call `jQuery.noConflict()`, and use `jQuery` (that's a variable name) instead of using `$` for jQuery.

Comment: My apologies if I misunderstood what you're asking. `$` _should_ be the only conflicting variable name. In JavaScript, variable names can be reused as long as they are in different scopes - so no need to renamed every repeated variable name. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

you can try this too;

replace all `$$(` with `dbl(` and `$(` with `sgl(` in the javascript file (**compressed.js**).

then in the html file you need to change first two lines of your code, as follows;

```
sgl('slideshow').style.display='none';
sgl('wrapper').style.display='block';
```

Answer (score 0):

add the gsearch plug in and then do a jQuery.noConflict()

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google.com/jsapi"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1");</script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">google.load("search", "1");</script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.gSearch-1.0-min.js"></script>
                    <script>

                    jQuery.noConflict();
                    jQuery(document).ready(function()     {     
                                jQuery("#search-results").gSearch({
                                            search_text : 'what you want to search',
                                            count : 8,
                                            site : 'your site url',
                                            pagination : true            
                                });
                    });    


                    </script>
```

Side Note: google does not issue the api key so remove it with that in mind see this link:
http://gsearch.scottreeddesign.com/documentation.html